# Lowermost limit on energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity

We know the lowest possible temperature that can exist -even if it is impossible to reach - being 0K. We also know the highest temperature with our current model of physics, that being the Planck Temperature.
This applies to other areas as the smallest possible unit of length and time, all Planck Units.

As such, is there a minimum amount of energy, in which lower energy isn’t possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is a thermodynamic variable, and describes systems of particles. The Planck units have to do with the definition of space time and matter/energy.

Energy is one of the variables of the s[pecial relativity four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) describing all matter, $(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ whose "length" is the invariant mass $m_0$. So if there is a massive particle the minimum energy will be the invariant mass, given by the equation

[image: invarm] and cannot be zero.

In the case of zero mass particles, the minimum energy can be zero (to be mathematically correct can approach zero). Take the photon whose energy is equal to $hν$, where $h$ is the [Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) and $ν$ the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave built up by a multitude of such photons. There is no limit to how small $ν$ can become, it can approach as close to zero as one can measure ( which means the classical electromagnetic wave composed of such photons would have a wavelength approaching infinity).

Comment: Thank you for your time answering this. From your information I want to bring two things.

Comment: Firstly, although it does seem mathematically possible for a photon to have an infinite wavelength, there is some lingering doubt as this reminds me of an inverse scenario to a Kugelblitz. Applying our current understanding of physics, there is no limit as to how luminous an object can be or how energetic a photon can be; however if you only look at the this you omit the possibility of a Kugelblitz forming. To me it seems as if the same happens here. Am I making sense? Feel free to poke around this question

Comment: To make more to the point on the photon, as I stated before, from the set of equation defining the energy of a photon on it’s wavelength and frequency, there is no limit as to how large it can get. Nonetheless there is an upper limit to a photon’s energy at ~267 GeV at the Electroweak Symmetry break. It seems entirely plausible to me that although you could theoretically get a photon of infinite wavelength and infinitesimal frequency or viceversa as you say, it doesn’t seem plausible as the cases mentioned above

Comment: The fact that ball lightning can be seen, and that it has not been explained how does not mean that the individual photons making the light up are different than other photons.   It means that one should look for a mechanism that generates photons . Light is a confluence of photons and can be as complicated as you want.

Comment: I do not see why symmetry breaking affects photons,it affects all gauge bosons. Anyway you ask for a lower limit in energy. Please be clear that a photon does not have a wavelength. The frequency associated with ν appears **only in the probability distribution**, has nothing to do with a space wave. see here how individual  photons build a classical interference pattern. Each photon is a dot. https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/